# jquery wordpress echo symbol error

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm have code jquery in wordpress

```
<script>
    var availableZtour = [<?php query_posts('category_name=Catname&showposts=5&orderby=date'); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?>",<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>];
    $( "#ztour" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableZtour
    });
  });
</script>
```

and i'm add post tite:

This - is - title - post1

but in input jquery echo : `["This &#8211; is &#8211 title &#8211; post1", "This &#8211; is &#8211; title &#8211; post2", ...etc ]`

How to input jquery echo : ["This - is - title - post1", "This - is - title - post2",...etc ]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to tidy your code, and your last `});` doesn't seem to belong to anywhere:

```
<script>
    var availableZtour = [
        <?php
        query_posts('category_name=Catname&showposts=5&orderby=date');
        if (have_posts()) {
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                echo '"';
                the_title();
                echo '", ';
            }
        }
        wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
    ];

    $( "#ztour" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableZtour
    });
  }); <----------------------------------------- THIS??
</script>
```

Btw I refactorized a bit your code so it's human readable, anyway I don't think that's the problem.

The output `&#8211;` is a long hyphen, it's been encoded so it don't mess up passing that character around, It's probably produced when you wrote the hyphen in a word document or any editor, and it automatically converted it into that non-standard but more "beatiful" hyphen (on its own believe).

It's not really an issue, if you output that on html it will look like – <---- this, notice the difference:

- – <-- weird hyphen
- `-` <-- normal hyphen

You can either try to replace the `&#8211;` with a normal hyphen from javascript, from your backend, and or database if you don't want that to appear.

Answer (score 0):

My script :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableZtour = [<?php query_posts('category_name=ztour&showposts=5&orderby=date'); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?>",<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>];
    $( "#ztour" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableZtour
    });
}); ---> Is true
```

I'm add normal hyphen `-` to post : how to echo script as normal hyphen `-` not `&#8211;`
If  i'm add – weird hyphen => script echo – weird hyphen but is not good => i have to do copy paste it's up one hyphen

Thanks